# dealing with the occurrence of buffer overflow and indefinite behavior in a program that performs a two-way communication

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, bidirectional

how can I modify the program so as to eliminate the danger of buffer overflow and modify it so as to prevent undefined behavior in the sequence `if (isalpha (res_buf [i])) res_buf [i] = toupper (res_buf [ i]);`?

The implementation uses 2 pipes for a two-way communication. (parent-child)

I would also like to say a few works about the performance of the program

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXBUF 1024

void err_exit(const char *msg)
{
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main()
{
    char buf[MAXBUF];
    int parent_w[2], child_w[2];
    ssize_t n;
    char res_buf[MAXBUF];
    size_t sz;

    if (pipe(parent_w) == -1)
        err_exit("pipe");
    if (pipe(child_w) == -1)
        err_exit("pipe");

    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        err_exit("fork");

    case 0:
        /* child */
        if (close(parent_w[1]) == -1)
            err_exit("close");
        if (close(child_w[0]) == -1)
            err_exit("close");

        while (1)
        {
            strcpy(res_buf, "");
            n = read(parent_w[0], buf, MAXBUF);
            if (n == -1)
                err_exit("read");

            if (n == 0)
                break;

            strncpy(res_buf, buf, MAXBUF);
            sz = strlen(res_buf);
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
                if (isalpha(res_buf[i]))
                    res_buf[i] = toupper(res_buf[i]);

            if (write(child_w[1], res_buf, strlen(res_buf) + 1) != strlen(buf) + 1)
                err_exit("write");
        }

        if (close(parent_w[0]) == -1)
            err_exit("close");
        if (close(child_w[1]) == -1)
            err_exit("close");

        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    /* parent */
    if (close(parent_w[0]) == -1)
        err_exit("close");
    if (close(child_w[1]) == -1)
        err_exit("close");

    while (1)
    {
        if (scanf("%s", buf) == -1)
            break;

        if (write(parent_w[1], buf, strlen(buf) + 1) != strlen(buf) + 1)
            err_exit("write");

        strcpy(res_buf, "");
        n = read(child_w[0], buf, MAXBUF);
        if (n == -1)
            err_exit("read");

        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }

    if (close(parent_w[1]) == -1)
        err_exit("close");
    if (close(child_w[0]) == -1)
        err_exit("close");

    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be careful, the [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) function might not add a null-terminator at the end. And considering your buffer sizes, the amount you might read and the amount you copy, there's not even place for the null-terminator. So any other string function you use (like when calling `strlen(res_buf)`) might give you undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, you have no buffer-overflow protection in `scanf("%s", buf)`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need the `isalpha` check. The `toupper` function will only turn lower-case letters to upper-case, and return any other character unmodified.

Comment: Replace with: `res_buf[i] = toupper((unsigned char) res_buf[i]);`

Comment: As a rule of thumb, C strings should be used only as an in-memory representation, not as a part of a communication protocol.

Comment: But overall, you seem to be asking for a general review of the program for buffer overflow risks, with recommended mitigations.  That's far too broad for an SO question, but if the program compiles and generally works then it such a request would probably be on topic for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).